# Convert pixel value histogram to table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, histogram

I am working in QGIS 2.1 with the National Land Cover Database 2006 land cover layer. It is a raster layer with pixel values corresponding to different land cover types. I have clipped this raster to a buffer layer around my study site. Now I want to analyze the proportion of each land cover type within the site radius. I can view the frequency of each pixel value in the histogram tab of the layer properties window, but I would like to see the pixel frequency data in a table so that I can perform calculations on it. Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved what you want to do with the [LECOS plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LecoS/) (Landscape ecology statistics). It works fine on 2.8, but I've seen it crash on 2.10. Hope it helps you.